# Insanity joining Server 12.04 to Windows AD

Tags: active-directory, likewise

I've seen lots of stuff about this error on the internet, but had no luck implementing a solution. I'm trying to use Likewise-Open to join an Ubuntu Server 12.04 machine to a Windows Active Dicrectory domain controller and having absolutely no luck.  I run: `sudo domainjoin-cli join my.domain.gob ADMINISTRATOR` and get back (after putting in the admin password):

```
Error: DNS_ERROR_BAD_PACKET [code 0x0000251e]
A bad packet was recieved from a DNS server. Potentially the requested address does not exist.
```

I have heard that WAD insists on being your only nameserver, and in attempts to make that work, I've tried editing /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces but none of that has worked either.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Active Directory machine as the primary DNS server solved this for me.

You may also want to modify `/etc/resolv.conf` by adding entries for both your domain name and Domain Controller.

I also recommend you install WINS on your DC in addition to DNS.